# How do i remove all the junk symbols for json so i can iterate through it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have generated a `json` array from an `XML` object. but it contains '@' symbols and `&quot;` symbols because of this jquery `each()` fails to iterate. is there a way to cleanup this. because when I hard code a json array and check in the `console.log()` there weren't any `@symbols` or `&quot;` But if the json was generated from an XML source it add those junk symbols.

What I want to know is, is there away to iterate through this `xml` without removing those junk values?  My purpose is to extract values and regenerate a new json with some newly added properties

Here is the currently generated json:

```
$({&quot;class&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;SOCIAL HISTORY&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Never&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Occasionally&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;4&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Socially&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;5&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Is Alcoholic&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; History of Alcoholism&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; None&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;26&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Alcoholism Screen Question&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;39&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;40&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;39&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? &quot;}}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Married&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; x 10 years&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;15&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Divorced&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Divorced&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Single&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;12&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Single&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Recreational drug use&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;13&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;:Recreational drug use&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;OCCUPATION&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;14&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; works for  x 27 years&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;25&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;14&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; 1 child&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;16&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;: 1 child&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; 2/3/4/5/6 children&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;: 2/3/4/5/6 children&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Activities&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; walks regularly&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;19&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: walks regularly&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; cycles for exercise&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;20&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: cycles for exercise&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; runs 3 days/week&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;21&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: runs 3 days/week&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; hunting and fishing&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;22&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: hunting and fishing&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; hiking and camping&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;23&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: hiking and camping&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; swims regularly&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;24&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: swims regularly&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;10/pk year&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;32&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Quit Date&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;35&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Quit Date&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Year Started&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;36&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Year Started&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;41&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;SocHx Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;42&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;SocHx Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;}]}]}}).each(function(index, item))
```

as you can see json value shown has a lot formatting junk values

here is the video link to show of the xml document and what the browser display after generating the json [video link](https://youtu.be/HZ6wyMSJZME)

here is the XML file

```
<class Title="SOCIAL HISTORY" ID="1" ParentID="0">
  <helpNavNode Title="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION" ID="2" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Never" ID="3" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Occasionally" ID="4" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Socially" ID="5" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)" ID="6" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Is Alcoholic" ID="7" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" History of Alcoholism" ID="8" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" None" ID="26" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None" />
    <helpNavNode Title="Alcoholism Screen Question" ID="39" ParentID="2">
      <helpNavNode Title=" Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? " ID="40" ParentID="39" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? " />
    </helpNavNode>
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="MARITAL STATUS" ID="9" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Married" ID="10" ParentID="9">
      <helpNavNode Title=" x 10 years" ID="15" ParentID="10" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years" />
    </helpNavNode>
    <helpNavNode Title=" Divorced" ID="11" ParentID="9" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Divorced" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Single" ID="12" ParentID="9" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Single" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="Recreational drug use" ID="13" ParentID="1" Narrative=":Recreational drug use" />
  <helpNavNode Title="OCCUPATION" ID="14" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" works for  x 27 years" ID="25" ParentID="14" Narrative="OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title=" 1 child" ID="16" ParentID="1" Narrative=": 1 child" />
  <helpNavNode Title=" 2/3/4/5/6 children" ID="17" ParentID="1" Narrative=": 2/3/4/5/6 children" />
  <helpNavNode Title="Activities" ID="18" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" walks regularly" ID="19" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: walks regularly" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" cycles for exercise" ID="20" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: cycles for exercise" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" runs 3 days/week" ID="21" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: runs 3 days/week" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" hunting and fishing" ID="22" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: hunting and fishing" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" hiking and camping" ID="23" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: hiking and camping" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" swims regularly" ID="24" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: swims regularly" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="Tobacco Use" ID="27" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title="Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless" ID="30" ParentID="27">
      <helpNavNode Title="10/pk year" ID="32" ParentID="30" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year" />
    </helpNavNode>
    <helpNavNode Title="Quit Date" ID="35" ParentID="27" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Quit Date" />
    <helpNavNode Title="Year Started" ID="36" ParentID="27" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Year Started" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="SocHx  Template" ID="37" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " ID="41" ParentID="37" Narrative="SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " ID="42" ParentID="37" Narrative="SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " />
  </helpNavNode>
</class>
```

here the code to generate json in the view

```
@{    
    var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath(Url.Content(@"~/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml")));
    var jsonObj=JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xdoc);
}
```

here is the jquery code to access the generated json object:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            console.log( @jsonObj);

            $(@jsonObj).each(function (index, item) {
                console.log( item[0] );
            });
          });
</script>
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to click a random video link on the internet, so please explain in words how the XML document is being converted to JSON. It sounds like you're pulling something meant for display in HTML rather than actual JSON, which is required to have actual `"` characters, not entities...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan apologies for trimmed down post before i thought the video explains : ) but have updated my OP

Comment: Please have a read of this:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there's a ton of "code" here which makes it almost impossible (or at least time consuming) to determine your actual problem.

Comment: @zeelong No worries. Now that I see your code, this is probably a duplicate. Use `@Html.Raw(@jsonObj)`. Right now it's encoding your JSON as HTML.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan still it displays an '@' symbol before 'ID' and Title

Comment: At this point I'd suggest putting a breakpoint in that server-side code and seeing what the value of `jsonObj` is before page rendering. You might also consider changing your JS code to be more like `var x = JSON.parse("@Html.Raw(jsonObj)");` and see what x is, or if there is an error in the console at that point. Sounds like `SerializeXmlNode` may not do what you want.